# При добавлении кнопки на форму, возникает ошибка

Tags: c#, winforms

В проект добавил cs файл, туда вписал кнопку. 0 ошибок.
Но при добавлении кнопки на форму, возникает данная ошибка.

[image]

Как ее исправить?

Ниже код файла

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyButton
{
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        private int borderSize = 0;
        private int borderRadius = 50;
        private Color borderColor = Color.DodgerBlue;

        public int BorderSize
        {
            get => borderSize;
            set { borderSize = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public int BorderRadius
        {
            get => borderRadius;
            set { borderRadius = (value <= Height) ? value : Height; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public Color BorderColor { 
            get => BackColor; set { BackColor = value; } 
        }
        public Color TextColor { 
            get => ForeColor; set { ForeColor = value;} 
        }

        public MyButton(EventHandler Vutton_Resize)
        {
            Size = new Size(100, 200);
            FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            BackColor = Color.Blue;
            ForeColor = Color.White;

            Resize += new EventHandler(Vutton_Resize);
        }

        private void Button_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (borderRadius > Height) borderRadius = Height;
        }

        private GraphicsPath GetFigurePath(RectangleF rectangle, float radius)
        {
            GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();

            graphicsPath.StartFigure();

            graphicsPath.AddArc(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
            graphicsPath.AddArc(rectangle.Width - radius, rectangle.Y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
            graphicsPath.AddArc(rectangle.Width - radius, rectangle.Height - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90);
            graphicsPath.AddArc(rectangle.X, rectangle.Height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
            graphicsPath.CloseFigure();

            return graphicsPath;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pevent);
            pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            RectangleF rectangleSurface = new RectangleF(0, 0, Width, Height);
            RectangleF rectangleBorder = new RectangleF(1, 1, Width - 0.5F, Height - 1);

            if (borderRadius > 0)
            {
                using (GraphicsPath graphicsPathSurface = GetFigurePath(rectangleSurface, borderRadius))
                using (GraphicsPath graphicsPathBorder = GetFigurePath(rectangleBorder, borderRadius - 1F))
                using (Pen penSurface = new Pen(Parent.BackColor, 2))
                using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
                {
                    penBorder.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                    Region = new Region(graphicsPathSurface);
                    pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(penBorder, graphicsPathSurface);

                    if (borderSize >= 1)
                        pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(penBorder, graphicsPathBorder);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Region = new Region(rectangleSurface);
                if (borderSize >= 1)
                    using (Pen penBorder = new Pen (borderColor, borderSize))
                    {
                        penBorder.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                        pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penBorder, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
                    }
            }
        }
        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            Parent.BackColorChanged += new EventHandler(Container_BackColorChanged);
        }
        private void Container_BackColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(DesignMode) Invalidate();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в скриншоте сообщения об ошибке, в третьей строке написано: DesignToolsServerException: Constructor on type 'MyButton.MyButton' not found. В вашем коде есть конструктор, но он принимает парамтер.

```
public MyButton(EventHandler Vutton_Resize)
{
    Size = new Size(100, 200);
    FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    BackColor = Color.Blue;
    ForeColor = Color.White;

    Resize += new EventHandler(Vutton_Resize);
}
```

Когда вы вытаскиваете кноку на форму, должен быть конструктор без параметров, DesignTool не знает какой параметр нужно передать, точнее не знает как этот параметр инициализировать. В общем, когда вы добавили в код конструктор с параметром, вы тем самым отказались от конструктора поумолчанию и если он вам нужен, его нужно указать явно. Т.е. в вашем коде, нужно добавить конструктор, который я написал в первом ответе где-нить рядом с этим конструктором.
Перед тем как постить сюда ответ, я создал проект у себя, внёс изменения и запустил его. Но это лишь, даст возможность запустить проект, что бы кнопка была такая, какую вы хотели, нужно вынести все параметры с вашего конструктора в констркутор поумолчанию. В общем вот код двух конструкторов:

```
public MyButton(EventHandler Vutton_Resize) : this()
{
    Resize += new EventHandler(Vutton_Resize);
}

public MyButton() : base()
{
    Size = new Size(100, 200);
    FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    BackColor = Color.Blue;
    ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

После того, как внесёте эти изменения, пересоберите решение и можете запустить. Ниже скрин:

[image: Перетаскиваю кнопку на форму]

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в свой класс конструктор без параметров, пересоберите решение и попробуйте снова вытащить вашу кнопку на форму.

```
public MyButton() : base()
{
    // свойства кнопки поумолчанию
}
```